# Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster - Asking for credentials during installation - Mac M2 ARM 64 - Installing virtual desktop with VMware Fusion

Tags: arm, 23.04

The install screen shows invalid user 'ubuntu'.

[image: The install screen shows - invalid user 'ubuntu']

Downloaded the ARM64 ISO desktop image from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/. I'm trying to install the image with VMware Fusion.

It keeps asking for Username and password.

First time installation window asks for username and password:

[image: First time installation window asks for username and password]

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exact same issue.

I believe there is an alternative to install Ubuntu 23.04/22.04 LTS via server iso and converting into desktop.
I've followed below mentioned steps and it worked for both 22.04 & 23.04.

Guide: https://communities.vmware.com/wbsdv95928/attachments/wbsdv95928/3006/558/30/Fusion%2013%20for%20Apple%20Silicon%20Companion%20v16.pdf

Comment: I might install OK, but the graphics performance could be substandard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try typing **ubuntu** as the password. I think that the the default password